# Eevee - Material Shader - "Ray Length" or Z-index equivalent?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Is there a method of controlling EEVEE shader node values based on distance from the camera? (Something like "Light Path > Ray Length" provides for Cycles shaders.)

I know you can render a Z-depth pass for compositing, but I would like to use this information in a shader node.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my own question: the "Camera Data" input node has "View Distance" and "View Z-Depth" outputs.